# Why can't Doctrine retrieve my model data?

Tags: php, doctrine

So, I'm trying to use Doctrine to retrieve some data. I have some basic code like this:

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection(CONNECTION_STRING);
$site = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Site')->find('00024');
echo $site->SiteName;
```

However, this keeps throwing a SQL error that 'column siteid does not exist'. When I look at the exception the SQL query is this (you can see the error is that the inner_tbl alias for siteid is set to s__siteid, so querying inner_tabl.siteid is what's broken):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    [inner_tbl].[siteid] AS [s__siteid]
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1 
        [s].[siteid] AS [s__siteid],
        [s].[name] AS [s__name], 
        [s].[address] AS [s__address], 
        [s].[city] AS [s__city], 
        [s].[zip] AS [s__zip], 
        [s].[state] AS [s__state], 
        [s].[region] AS [s__region], 
        [s].[callprocessor] AS [s__callprocessor], 
        [s].[active] AS [s__active], [s].[dateadded] AS [s__dateadded] 
    FROM [Sites] [s] 
    WHERE ([s].[siteid] = '00024')
    ) AS [inner_tbl]
```

Why is the query being generated this way? Could it be the way the Yaml schema is laid out?

```
Site:
  connection: 0
  tableName: Sites
  columns:
    siteid:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: true
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(300)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    address:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    city:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    zip:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    state:
      type: string(2)
      fixed: true
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    region:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      default: (5)
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    callprocessor:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    active:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    dateadded:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      default: (getdate())
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to one of the developers (Johnathan Wage) in the IRC room and he says that SQL may work, but that there are probably bugs (I'm assuming this is one). He also said that Doctrine was written specifically with MySQL in mind.